# How to integrate external Office 365 Login with .NET Application

Tags: .net-core, active-directory, office365, single-sign-on

How are you doing?

I have a .NET Core Web application. I order to perform a Login in this app, it is necessary register the Tenant and the user accounts for that Tenant, manually.

But now, I have two new companies that would like to use Single Sign On, using the Office 365 Active Directory Accounts.

And the things become a little bit fog in my mind with that request.

And some questions are surrounding my mind, such as:

1. How to implement the Office 365 logins?
2. The Office 365 signature it's not mine. Each company that pretend to use my App,  has it is own signature. How to link their signature with my app? Is it necessary any kind of "appsecret" and "appkey" provided by them? Is it possible to use multiple  Office 365 signatures to provide single sign on to them?
3. How the companies can manage who will have access in my App?

Answer (score 0):

1. Microsoft 365 uses Azure Active Directory ([Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/about-microsoft-365-identity?view=o365-worldwide)). You can see a tutorial on integrating Azure AD auth here: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory/v2#register-your-app-with-azure-ad
2. I don't fully understand your question
3. Companies can manage users on the [Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/)

Comment: Hi, tks for provide me some guidance. I reformulated the "2" question topic.